# Mysql запрос для пагинации с параметром

Tags: mysql

Не могу понять, как должен выглядеть запрос в базу для пагинации. Перечитал кучу всего в гугле, но не нашел ничего полезного. Может подскажете?

Как пример я хочу сделать выборку по полю number, с позиции 15 по 20.

Comment: [Крутить вниз до слов "Выражение LIMIT может..."](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SELECT.html)

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/3h4gKEm а почему он выводит не 5 результатов, а 9?

Comment: у вас по видимому всего 19 строк в таблице orders . А запрос работает правильно вы пытаетесь получить 15 результатов со смещением 10. Внимательнее читайте документацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY number LIMIT 15, 5
#15 - смещение, 5 - количество записей на странице
```

На самом деле, в таком запросе покажутся записи с 16 по 20 включительно. Я думаю это как раз, то что вам надо, если на странице по 5 записей.